# drawableStart not showing drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android, and one of the challenges in the book said to add the previous button on my own. I did, and asked a friend for help putting the arrow on the left side, and he did, but he couldn’t figure out why `drawableStart` didn’t work. (`drawableLeft` did work)

Anyone know why `drawableStart` didn’t work? Or better yet: how to fix it?

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:text="@string/previous_button"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:text="@string/next_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code under themes.xml :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.GeoQuiz" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please post the xml layout code in text not pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're using Material design buttons, so use `android:icon` instead of `android:drawableStart`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:text="@string/previous_button"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/next_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update:

> Didn't work. Now it doesn't show either arrow. And the program doesn't run in the emulator anymore

Appears to be a compatibility issue with `android` directive so, change it to `app` directive instead and added a style of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog` as you use

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:text="@string/previous_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/next_button"/>
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog"
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Now it doesn't show either arrow. And the program doesn't run in the emulator anymore. Maybe I didn't add the library?

Comment: can you tell if you use `Theme.MaterialComponents` as the main theme `sytles.xml` or one of its subordinates ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started learning android, I don't know what that means. Is that supposed to be in the same file (activity_main.xml)? All that is on top there (that looks like imported libraries) is : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` should I add `Theme.MaterialComponents` over there?

Comment: np, in the left pane, there is a file under `res\values\styles.xml` can you share its content?

Comment: It doesn’t exist. Under res/values is: colors.xml, strings.xml and the themes folder which holds 2 files of themes.xml (one has “night” in parenthesis) should I add a styles file?

Comment: it seems it's themes.xml, the name doesn't matter, but it is usually styles.xml .. please share it

Comment: @Doragon now please see the update section in answer

Comment: That got rid of the background for the button, but it didn't add the arrow in. I realized that I was using `android:icon` instead of `app:icon`. I changed it, and I can now see the arrows, but the "next" arrow is now on the wrong side. (`> NEXT`, instead of `NEXT >`)

Answer (score 2):

After a whole lot of searching I finally figured out how to make it work
android:drawableStart not working seems to be an issue and here is the link to the issue and fix https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1174

Here's the fix

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/previous_button"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"/>
```

Instead of using drawableBottom|Top|Left|... use MaterialButton's attributes app:icon, app:iconGravity and app:iconTint

Note drawableStart seems to be the only one with the issue the others work

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/your_image"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/your_image"/>
```

Then for Left

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    app:iconTint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the answers above here, this seems to be the easiest way to go.
I modified it to Arabic in the settings and confirmed that it works properly.

```
<Button
    app:icon="@drawable/baseline_add_24_white"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
/>
```